# JavaScript, will unused arrays affect performance?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I manipulate data using D3.js.

I created many arrays to obtain the final array with desired data structure.

As each arrays contain thousands of objects each, I was wondering if they will affect the browser's performance even though these arrays are no longer in use?

Will emptying/deleting these arrays improve the performance?

As there are many different libraries and events (filters, onclick, etc) used, it is hard for me to accurately determine the performance.

E.g.

```
array1.forEach(function(d){
d.v1 = +d.v1;
...
});

array2 = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.state; }).entries(array1);

array3 = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.state; }).rollup(...).9entries(array1);

array4 = [];
for (i in array3) {
...
array4.push(...) };

array5
...
array10
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: An advice: remove the d3 tag from the question and post it again just with the javascript tag, alone. You'll have way more experts paying attention to your question.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Comment: If they are no longer in use, they will get garbage-collected automatically. You don't need to empty them. Just make sure that nothing references them any more (the code you've shown is too generic to give specific advise)

Comment: Simply removing references to arrays (for example, assigning mutable variables with new values, or leaving entire scope) signals to garbage collector that they can be freed from memory.

Comment: unused arrays that are initialised but never used may actually be removed by a dead code optimiser if you a preprocessor set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring to the comments, I gathered that unused arrays will get garbage-collected automatically. Hence, they will not affect the memory.

I hereby close this question.